# c# htmlagilitypack get tags by inline attributes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

this is my html :

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <table>
                ...
            </table>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td width="165"></td>
                    <td width="165"></td>
                    <td width="165"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

there are lots of table, how to get td tags only with [width="165"] attribute? i am using htmlagilitypack in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HAP's `SelectNodes()` method passing the following XPath as argument :

```
//td[@width=165]
```

Comment: wow thank, i didn't relize that ;) i thought it would works only classes and id